# Silverstripe 3 form not executed

Tags: php, silverstripe

I create `ContactPage.php` type and also create form class `ContactForm.php` with custom template `ContactForm.ss`. After submitting form nothing was happening. Where is my mistake?

ContactForm.php:

```
class ContactForm extends Form {
    public function __construct($controller, $name, $arguments = array()) {
        $fields = new FieldList();
        $fields->push(TextField::create('From', 'Email'));
        $fields->push(TextField::create('Subject', 'Tema'));
        $fields->push(TextField::create('Message', 'Message'));

        $actions = new FieldList(FormAction::create('doSendMessage')->setTitle('Kontakt'));
        $validator = new RequiredFields('From', 'Subject', 'Message');

        parent::__construct($controller, $name, $fields, $actions, $validator);
    }

    public function doSendMessage($data, Form $form) {
        // Test 
        Controller::curr()->redirect('http://www.google.com');
    }

    public function forTemplate() {
        return $this->renderWith([
            $this->class,
            'Form'
        ]);
    }
}
```

ContactPage.php:

```
class ContactPage extends Page {
}

class ContactPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = [
        'MyContactForm'
    ];

    public function init() {
        parent::init(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }

    public function MyContactForm() {
        return new ContactForm($this, 'MyContactForm');
    }
}
```

ContactForm.ss:

```
 <form $FormAttributes>
    <label for="{$FormName}_Email">Email adresa</label>
    $Fields.dataFieldByName(From)
    <label for="{$FormName}_Email">Tema</label>
    $Fields.dataFieldByName(Subject)
    <label for="{$FormName}_Email">Poruka</label>
    $Fields.dataFieldByName(Message)
    $Fields.dataFieldByName(SecurityID)
    <% if $Actions %>
       <% loop $Actions %>
          $Field
       <% end_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed a version of SilverStripe 3.5 with this code and it works for me. When you submit, it will redirect to google which says that the `doSendMessage` function is firing.

You are missing a Layout for `ContactPage`. In the templates/Layout directory, you need to create a silverstripe template called `ContactPage.ss`

Use something like:

```
<% include SideBar %>
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
  <article>
    <h1>$Title</h1>
    <div class="content">$Content</div>
  </article>
  $Form
  $CommentsForm
  $MyContactForm
</div>
```

The important part is having the `$MyContactForm` token.